# WPF Combobox with ItemsSource - What path do I set to access this databinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I'm having a problem setting the Binding/Path property in my XAML.

I know this ComboBox's `ItemSource` property is updating properly, since I get a bunch of empty text-boxes when I update the `viewmodel` (instead of textboxes with text, which is what I expect).

So I believe the Binding in the `DataTemplate` section of my ComboBox needs a different binding path, but I'm not sure what to set the binding path to.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Locations}" Visibility="{Binding SettingsOptionsVisibility}" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="locationCB" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="locationCB_SelectionChanged"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="350" Height="30" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsEnabled="False" Focusable="False">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**Here's a picture of my LocationCB's ItemsSource in the Watch List in my Codebehind:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkiHU.jpg

As expected, my combobox is populated with 8 (textless) elements. What do I need to do to get my binding the text to Name to connect up?

EDIT: code for the Locations object in the ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
```

And code for the Location class wrapped in the observable collection, as requested:

```
public class Location
{
    public Guid LocationID;
    public Guid ParentID;
    public String Name;
    public bool isValid;
}
```

Comment: Is `Name` a property defined in `Location` class? Post code for that as well.

Comment: Get rid of the `<StackPanel>` element, it should just be a textbox inside of itemtemplate

Comment: Rohit, posted, and yes; Netscape, done, same problem though.

Comment: You have `IsHitTestVisible` and `IsEnabled` set to false. It doesn't seem like you would be able to open the ComboBox.

Comment: @John - As stated before `Name` should be a property and not field. Convert field to property and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the fields of your location object to properties:

```
public class Location
{
    public Guid LocationID { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool isValid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to make `Location` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well

Comment: Fields and properties are different things. The `get;` and `set;` syntax creates a property with a default backing field. WPF does not bind to fields.

Answer (score 1):

You should be binding to properties and not variables. Instead of

```
public string Name;
```

You should change the above to

```
public string Name {get;set;}
```

Even better, can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged..