# how to change multiple labels based on their name

Tags: c#, wpf

i've got a list of comboboxes called cb1,cb2,cb3 etc. and a label lb1 lb2 lb3 next to each combobox . the combobox contains 3 values each, low medium and high, and every time a combobox item is selected, theres a label next to the combobox showing a "value",so "low" shows 25, medium shows 50 etc. i managed to have one single routine that controls all the comboboxes, like this:

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    string qr = cb.SelectedItem.ToString();
    switch (qr) {
    case "low":
        lb11.Content = "25";
    break;
    case "medium":
        lb11.Content = "50";
    break;
    case "high":
        lb11.Content = "75";
    break;
}
```

i need to change a label next to it according to the combobox name, say the combo is called cb22, i need to change label named lb22 etc.

Comment: no its a wpf in c#

Comment: Looking for this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case i would use `Binding` together with `ValueConverter`, because processing UI stuff in the code behind is agains the idea of `WPF`. The
aim is to separate `UI` logic from `codebehind`.

For more information take a look on SO, for example:

1. [WPF Databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7472/2630261)
2. [WPF Combobox with ItemsSource - What path do I set to access this databinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22819714/2630261)

Answer (score 0):

solved,thanks a lot. i dunno if its the proper way to deal with it,but i just declared the label as:

> var lb = (Label)this.FindName("label" + cb.Name);

and then i can change the value in the switch case using lb.content

Comment: @frankieht remember, that this is a kind of solution, but not the way you should work using `WPF`. But good it works :)